# No matching distribution found for qtsvg when running spyder

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, spyder

I have Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with Python 2.7.6 and I just installed `spyder` IDE using `pip`. However, when I run it I get the following warnings (which from what I found they are OK) but so far I could not resolve them. In addition, I get an error message which prevents `spyder` from running. Here are the details:

The warning message:

```
 RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
```

I tried to uninstall some libraries and install them again like (numpy, scipy, pandas, tensorflow, and keras) but I still get the same error.

Here is the error message which is the critical thing:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qtsvg (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for qtsvg
```

I tried to install `qtsvg` but I get again the same type of error. So what is the solution for this problem?